# disable HTML fields

Tags: javascript, dojo

So I have two form input fields which are mutually exclusive to each other(User can only type in any one of the two fields). I use `onKeyUp` event on these fields to disable each other. 
Once user types in the data and hits the submit button I make an Ajax call to refresh screen content and at this time the **typed in field** still contains the data typed prior to Ajax call but the other input field is no more disabled (as onKeyUp event never triggered). 
I tried using Dojo's `addOnLoad` event but and then checking for the length of Input fields but thats throwing an undefined error on input field. 
Any suggestions how to fix this scenario?
**PS: This page doesn't have a body tag and I can't add one either to use body onLoad event.**

Comment: @peachmaker, nope. Either Dojo or plain Javascript.

Comment: @Elias, give me few. I will post a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming in Dojo you have smth similar to handle your Ajax call

```
dojo.xhrPost({
    // The URL of the request
    url: "submit.php",
    // No content property -- just send the entire form
    form: dojo.byId("form"),
    // The success handler
    load: function(response) {
        messageNode.innerHTML = response;
    },
    // The error handler
    error: function() {
        messageNode.innerHTML = "Your ERROR message."
    },
    // The complete handler
    handle: function() {
        hasBeenSent = true;
    }
});
```

Then on complete handler - `handle`, which will fire both on success or error, you can re-disable the input

Comment: Zoltan, Thanks. great suggestion. Let me try and post back.

Comment: did it with callback function. Thanks.